# How to keep Windows 7 restarting the PC until no `restart requirement` is required?

Tags: windows-7, automation, windows-update, reboot

I cannot get new updates via Windows Update because the OS requires to restart - to finish previous/current installing stuff I guess.

The `restart requirement` is as below snapshot.

How can I make my Windows keep restarting loop automatically until no `restart requirement` is required?

[image]

Comment: Don't have the direct path but maybe you could figure it out?

Tip: try to see what flags (in registry) does that UI state read to show that icon. If there's a (theoretical) update_needs_restart=1 in registry, read it and set a startup task to restart your system until that update_needs_restart=0.

BTW, are you on a laptop?

Comment: How can we guard the big registry to detect the `update_needs_restart`?

Comment: I not using a laptop. It is a PC.

Answer (score 3):

Use [WSUS Offline Updater](http://download.wsusoffline.net) and let it handle the reboots for you. Designed for managing systems that can't connect to the network but it would work on your computer as well. It at least makes installing the updates for Windows, Office, etc. totally unattended.

Comment: +1 - autoit is always a good way to go for this sort of automation and it is nice when you find an existing project that does what you're looking to do.