# How to make Windows get updates, reboot _and_ shutdown?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, shutdown, automation, reboot

When using Windows' "install updates and shut down", the next boot (usually in the morning when one actually wants to start working) is rather tedious due to unfinished business. The alternative is manually letting Windows update install updates while remaining there, *then* rebooting, waiting for update completion and shutting down manually. But that means buying an earlier start in the morning by a later closing time.

So, is there any way to tell Windows 7 "I'm leaving now, get those updates, restart if you need to, and shut down in a way that you're ready tomorrow without pesky update remainders!"?

Answer (score 2):

This https://superuser.com/a/721956/382867 question has an answer that references the [WSUS Offline Updater](http://download.wsusoffline.net/)  which looks like a tool that allows you to pre-download all updates and then apply them automatically, rebooting your system as required.

Another possibility is to use Task Scheduler to issue a shutdown /r a couple of hours after you quit so that if a restart is required it'll be done for you.  This won't protect you from updates that need multiple restarts but those are fairly rare.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to run a PowerShell script called PSWindowsUpdate

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc

and wrap PSWindowsUpdate into this powershell script (called Resume on Reboot)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/223002/Reboot-and-Resume-PowerShell-Script

It really depends on how many computers you are talking about needing to run windows updates on, if you are on a windows domain, if you are using WSUS in your environment already, etc.   If you can provide some more details on the scope (how many computers, single PC or many, etc) I would be happy to expand this answer to give details on how to get the PS scripts working.